# xcode 6.x simulators are not showing up

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have a xcode 6.x project in which i made small changes. Now i want to submit it to app store. 
But none of the simulators are showing up.

[image: ios sim not showing]

i was using xcode 6.4 but then i download xcode 6.2 and it still doesn't work. How do archive it and submit it to appstore?

I cannot use latest xcode because the project is in swift so will have to make alot of changes, it's a big project.

Comment: @JAL doesn't work, so i updated the project to submit it :(

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen if the width of the Xcode window is too narrow.  Try resizing the window wider, and they should re-appear.

Comment: it disappears for me when resizing the window smaller.  If your cause is different, file a radar.

Comment: well thats not the issue.

Comment: then please file a radar because the only known cause is the one I mentioned.

Comment: well i updated my project and delete the old versions now